# Import Sheet1 Data From Multiple Workbooks From Specific Folder Into Single Workbook Using VBA Or Macros

Tags: excel, vba

Fetch Sheet1 Data From Multiple Workbook Into Single Workbook Using VBA Or Macros

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeExcels()

    Dim Path As String, FName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Path = ""
    FName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    With ThisWorkbook
        Do While FName <> ""
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & FName, ReadOnly:=True)
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                ws.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            Next ws
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            FName = Dir()
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Above Code Fetch All Sheets In a Workbook But I Need Sheet1 Data Only

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    ws.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
Next ws
```

To:

```
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
```

Or, if you meant the first worksheet instead of the one named Sheet1:

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: Code is looking right but it even cant run or throw an error

Comment: Then there is an error in the rest of your code. Please explain where the error appears and what the error is.

Comment: Cant Identify where the error acquired or specific line Please help me through

Comment: _Cant Identify where the error acquired or specific line_ There should be a bright yellow/red stripe across your code, this is where the error occurs, there is also a message box which pops up and gives you an error code. Either one would be appreciated. If your error is that the code runs but doesn't produce the output you expect please explain the difference between expectations and results.

Comment: Yes i do find yellow line without red error and popup message, I want to fetch sheet1 data to single workbook

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeExcels()
    Dim Path As String, FName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Path = "D:\BILL'S\Thankam\2019\June\Bills"
    FName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    With ThisWorkbook
        Do While FName <> ""
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & FName, ReadOnly:=True)
            wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            FName = Dir()
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Option Explicit
Sub MergeExcels()

```
Dim Path As String, FName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Path = "D:\BILL'S\Thankam\2019\June\Bills"
FName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
With ThisWorkbook
    Do While FName <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & FName, ReadOnly:=True)
        wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        FName = Dir()
    Loop
    End With
```

End Sub